# PHP, urlencoding is encoding wrong string

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry for this noobish question but I got stuck on this.

So what I am trying to do is:
to pass this data

```
$lines = 'Line 1\n Line 2\n Line 3\n';
array('lines' => $lines);
```

and I have to send this to another website via API
but the thing is, that when I send my API connection file 
uses urlencode to encode the data that I am sending via API

and while doing this encoding, php turns

```
'Line 1\n Line 2\n Line 3\n'
```

to

```
'Line 1%5Cn Line 2%5Cn Line 3%5Cn'
```

and when this data goes via API, the other website doesnt understand these lines.

What should I do, to pass this line uneffected by urlencode? I tried adding " " since it will make it as one string alone but it doesnt work since I have to get those lines as $lines.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: urlencoding if for url not for data

Comment: why is `$lines` in single quotes? and where's the encoding method?

Comment: If you want an array of lines then your code is back to front. $lines = array(); makes an empty array, then $lines[] = 'Line 1'; $lines[] = 'Line 2'; etc will add each item individually to the array

Comment: which API you're calling and what's their requirement

Comment: @StanleyCheung they need the lines to be sent as "Line 1\n  Line 2\n..."

Comment: Are you passing your data by json body? have you tried to use json_encode?